# Matching multilines using perl -e

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with the format

```
 location:
 rome

 participants:
 cesar
 pompei
 Sylla
```

And I am trying to invoke `perl` to get values given a key, for instance my function with parameter `participants` will return

```
 cesar
 pompei
 Sylla
```

The issue I am facing is that without the option `-n` it seems none of my regex works.
For instance I was expecting

```
> perl -e '/(.*)/ms && print "$1\n" ' input.txt
```

to print the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this alitle:

```
# cat file
location:
rome

participants:
cesar
pompei
Sylla
```

Now get `participants`:

```
# perl -e 'undef $/; $_=<>; /participants:\s*(.*?)(\n\n|$)/s && print "$1\n";' file
cesar
pompei
Sylla
```

UPD: As mentioned by TLP, it can be rewritten with -0 switch:

```
# perl -0777 -e '$_=<>; /participants:\s*(.*?)(\n\n|$)/s && print "$1\n";' file
cesar
pompei
Sylla
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! I will modify the trailing regex group `(\n\n|$)`, it is too restrictive. *ps: elaborate on -0777 as soon as you post :), this is what I was looking for*.

Answer (score 4):

While on the command line, you might as well use paragraph mode:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -00 -anlwe 
    '$h=shift @F; $a{$h}=[@F]; }{ print Dumper \%a;' ceasar.txt
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'participants:' => [
                               'cesar',
                               'pompei',
                               'Sylla'
                             ],
          'location:' => [
                           'rome'
                         ]
        };
```

Explanation:

- `-MData::Dumper` use the Data::Dumper module. This is just for demonstration and not relevant to your question.
- `-00` use paragraph mode, which means - simply put - setting the input record separator to `\n\n`, so that the input is split on double newlines.
- `-a` split the paragraphs on whitespace. You can qualify this with `-F'\n'` to make it split on newlines only.
- `-n` implicit `while (<>)` loop around the program.
- `-l` not strictly required for this example, but it handles newline endings for you in a convenient way.
- `@F` is the array that the autosplit option uses. Meaning we take the first word in the paragraph and make it the header, and the rest of the words the arguments.

Comment: Nice! The same with JSON::XS `perl -MJSON::XS -00 -anlwe '$h=shift @F; $a{$h}=[@F]; }{ $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;print $coder->encode (\%a);'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation on the command line switches! So `a` is an associative array of tables? pretty powerful...

Comment: @UmNyobe It's a hash, with headers as keys and arrays with names as values. Once you have parsed the input, you can easily access either header.

Answer (score 2):

By default `-n` and `-p` will feed input to your one-line script one line at a time. So to do use a multi-line search, you will have to tell `perl` to use a different record separator. Use the `-0` option for that.

To read the whole file in a single line:

```
perl -0777 -ne '...' input.txt
```

To use "paragraph mode" (split on two or more consecutive newlines, which might be what you want for this problem):

```
perl -00 -ne '...' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using -n you have to read the input explicitly, e.g.

```
while(<>){do...}
```

You aren't getting a match because you aren't actually reading anything from stdin.

Comment: yes, but I am already aware of `while(<>)` and I dont want to use it.